# Morphology algorithm how it work for left ventricles dicom image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

After so much search on google i find out few things hope so that correct for detecting Left ventricles of hearth and draw the Region of Interest(ROI) on MR Modality .

Can you give me please more detiails idea about "Morphology Algorithm" for tumore detection in heart of LV

Comment: Welcome to DSP.se! The community here is very friendly and helpful to the people who get stuck in their approaches and need some help to move on. But, please kindly remember **we are not your personal research assistant, or a teacher for rent**. Questions, like yours, asking "how to apply a field X to a problem Y" are generally frowned upon. Please, give detailed infromation about your problem. If you do not understand some morphological concept, or have a problem applying some specific approach to a problem, please describe your concrete problem and your approach so far, and we'll gladly help

Answer (score 2):

Morphology is more a framework than a single algorithm; there are many morphological image processing algorithms for many problems. They (more or less) try to enhance/impair objects on the image based on their shape (hence the name of this family of algorithms). I would strongly recommend reading [Morphological Image Analysis, Principles and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540429883) first, as it is a very good overview on the field, then you could try to choose an algorithm for your specific problem. As for a segmentation problem, I would look after morphological reconstruction and watershed algorithm ([this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQFjAD&url=http://www.vincent-net.com/luc/papers/93ieeeip_recons.pdf&ei=ROpnUaLnE-jW4ATOtIGoBg&usg=AFQjCNGVgCfUv3WqLCMaWvzd33oJYHaRZw&sig2=BhzRJnCPpWKsMnnsGlvxpQ&bvm=bv.45175338,d.Yms) article is an excellent starting point).

Comment: finaly i decided to choose morphological reconstruction algorithm